# Android Stuck partial wake locks despite not having the permission

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I'm having issues in a Xamarin android app.

Play console reports a high % of session with Stuck partial wake locks but I don't use wake locks.
I even added : `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" tools:node="remove" />`

I tried to check what could cause this but I don't have any idea since I use a lot of dependencies.

Google redacted the tag that causes this issue so I'm a bit lost.

Any idea/clue that could help me resolve this issue or help me find the culprit?

Edit : I managed to removed Wake_Lock permission but it is required by Work Manager on some lower API versions. So I'm stuck with it.

Comment: What's your android api version ?

Comment: Targeting api 29 with 21 for minimum